# Putting numeric data from an input file into a linked list

Tags: c++, io

I am writing a function that will **read** an input file and **write** the numbers into a linked list. There are two rows of numbers in the input file, an integer and a double:

**Int**
1
1
1
**Float**
1.2
1.4
2.4

except theyre in vertical rows. Think of it as a T chart, with 1 column being integer numbers and 1 column being floats. Each **row** of the column has 1 int and 1 float, so they are **grouped** together. I want to store **each** group of the table in a node of a linked list.
The question is, how do I read them into a linked list? Let's say I have created one of Class FlowList. FlowList has a **next** pointer, and a **node** which contains an integer and float storage.

```cpp
struct ListItem{
    int year;
    double flow;
};

struct Node{
    ListItem item;
    Node *next;
};

class FlowList{

    Node *headM;
```

So basically, if the numbers line up in the row/ are in the same group, (ie, 1 and 2.22 line up with each other) then they go into the same Node.

```
**year**                **flow**
    1                       1.5
    2                       3.3  <--------this row goes into one node of the 
                                          linked list
```

Here's a sample of what I wrote so far (it isn't much at all):

Also, the input file is guaranteed to have only numbers in it, so there is no worry about that.

```cpp
int readData(FlowList& x){

    int c=0; //counter which reads the number of nodes created.
    ifstream fpr;
    fpr.open("flow.txt");
    if(!fpr){
        cerr<<"Error in opening file";
        exit(1);
    }
//and then I have no idea what to do beyond here.
```

Now I'll create a new FlowList called x. The way to access the integer and float is by using the syntax below:

```cpp
x.head->item.year
x.head->item.flow
```

Im still very new to c++, so let me know if i need to clarify anything.
Thanks

Comment: Your description is not clear, as you are mixing up two issues.  First, what does a linked-list have to do with the ability to read in the data?   Please redo your post to show *exactly* the data layout.  Describing the layout is not clear.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have fixed it

Comment: Instead of a ListItem struct, you can use `std::pair<int, double>`. You access the members using the public `first` and `second` members. This is subjective to me, but if you're learning a linked list, it might be worth templating the list for more generic use.

Comment: You just listed a bunch of small, simple tasks. The trick to programming is don't over-complicate things. Do them one at a time, but make sure they work before you proceed to the next small simple task. Don't try to do everything at once before you test anything.

Comment: A nice trick to these linked list questions for programming 101 classes is "do it with the standard library" and then if you're not allowed to use the standard library, that's okay. You can now write your own linked list with code that already works, so you're not simultaneously dealing with bugs in your code that uses the list, and bugs in the linked list itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as two distinct problems.

First, I would write a simple method that does nothing but reads the file and cout's the data. This will help you figure out the I/O portion. That method isn't hard, maybe 5 lines or so.

Then I would implement the linked list code and just write a little program that creates 5 items of the list. This will help you figure out how to program a linked list. Do a few test operations so you know it's working.

Then combine the two.

This is a really good beginning programming problem.